# Maximum number of canvases (used as layers)?

Tags: html, canvas

I am writing an HTML5 canvas app in javascript.  I am using multiple canvas elements as layers to support animation without having to re-draw the whole image every frame.

Is there a **maximum number** of canvas elements that I can layer on top of each other in this way -- (and see an appropriate result on all of the HTML5 platforms, of course).

Thank you.

Comment: its so easy to test. just make a loop, and see when the browser will throw exception.

Comment: there is a nice article about [canvas layers](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/wa-canvashtml5layering/index.html#N1011D)

Answer (score 4):

I imagine you will probably hit a practical performance ceiling long before you hit the hard specified limit of somewhere between several thousand and 2,147,483,647 ... depending on the browser and what you're measuring (number of physical elements allowed on the DOM or the maximum allowable z-index).

This is correlated to another of my favorite answers to pretty much any question that involves the phrase "*maximum number*" - if you have to ask, you're probably Doing It Wrong™. Taking an approach that is aligned with the intended design is almost always just as possible, and avoids these unpleasant murky questions like "will my user's iPhone melt if I try to render 32,768 canvas elements stacked on top of each other?"

Answer (score 3):

This is a question of the limits of the DOM, which are large. I expect you will hit a *performance* bottleneck *before* you hit a hard limit.

The key in your situation, I would say, is to prepare some simple benchmarks/tests that dynamically generate Canvases (of arbitrary number), fill them with content, and add them to the DOM. You should be able to construct your tests in such a way where A) if there is a hard limit you will spot it (using identifiable canvas content or exception handling), or B) if there is a performance limit you will spot it (using profiling or timers). Then perform these tests on a variety of browsers to establish your practical "limit".

There are also great resources available here https://developers.facebook.com/html5/build/games/ from the Facebook HTML5 games initiative. Therein are links to articles and open source benchmarking tools that address and test different strategies similar to yours.